# asp.net mvc 3 routing aspx page from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to route from my controller to .aspx page. i am trying this but that doesn't work.

```
return Redirect("~/Views/Report/UygulamaYanitiRapor.aspx");
```

Below code routes but i couldn't get parameter with Request.QueryString["gelen"]. it comes  null.

```
return Redirect("~/Report/UygulamaYanitiRapor/0");

 routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Rapor",
            "Report/UygulamaYanitiRapor/{gelen}",//{gelen}/{id}",
            "~/Views/Report/UygulamaYanitiRapor.aspx",
            true, null,
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "outgoing", new MyCustomConstaint() } }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this walkthrough on how to set up routing for Asp.Net Web Forms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

I think the easiest way to get this working is to modify your aspx-page to check both `Request.QueryString` and `Page.RouteData.Values` for the same values, possibly with a preference for the QueryString values.